# Creating a before and after from a Registry key value on a remote server

Tags: powershell, comparison, registry

I'm a little lost as to why I'm unable to get a registry key value before, make a change then collect the value after the change to confirm the change was successful.

I'm using the following code which gets the correct values but doesn't reflect any changes I make to `LogMaxHistory` or `LogLevel`.

Am I doing something incorrect?

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $server)

    $RegSubKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\CCM\\Logging\\@Global", $true)

    $LogLevelBefore      = $RegSubKey.GetValue('LogLevel')
    $LogMaxHistoryBefore = $RegSubKey.GetValue('LogMaxHistory')

    $RegSubKey = $Reg.SetValue('LogLevel', '0', [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWORD)
    $RegSubKey = $Reg.SetValue('LogMaxHistory', '6', [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWORD)

    $RegCheck = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $server)
    $RegCheck = $RegCheck.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\CCM\\Logging\\@Global")

    $LogLevelAfter      = $RegCheck.GetValue('LogLevel')
    $LogMaxHistoryAfter = $RegCheck.GetValue('LogMaxHistory')

    [pscustomobject]@{
        ComputerName        = $server
        LogLevelBefore      = $LogLevelBefore
        LogMaxHistoryBefore = $LogMaxHistoryBefore
        LogLevelAfter       = $LogLevelAfter
        LogMaxHistoryAfter  = $LogMaxHistoryAfter
    }
    $Reg.Close()
    $RegCheck.Close()
    GSV -ComputerName $server -Name CcmExec | Restart-Service
}
```

Comment: After some searching, I landed [here](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/15009.aspx) which shows the registry change happening on one line.  Using the same one line approach, I get the value before the change using `GetValue` in place of `SetValue` and everything works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regquery

example

```
$before=reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\" /ve /s

$after=reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\" /ve /s

write-host "registry value $before and $after" -F green
```

Comment: I was aware of Reg Query but wanted to keep it PowerShell only, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overloaded method `OpenSubKey` with `RegistryKeyPermissionCheck` type and `RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree` argument (see: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128501(v=vs.110).aspx))?

Another aproach is to use registry drives as follows (simplified, you must change keys and properties):

```
$server = '.'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {
    $before = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDProgs -Name Property1
    Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDProgs -Name Property1 -Value (Get-Random)
    $after = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDProgs -Name Property1
    [psobject]@{Before = $before.Property1; After = $after.Property1}
} `
   | % { "Before = $($_.Before), After = $($_.After)" }
```

Comment: Looks good with one exception, I cannot use Invoke-Command.  I'll have to revisit this as time allows to get something working.

Comment: After looking around a bit, reading an article mentioning to export the Registry key to compare, I happened across something easier.  Just dump the value to a string.  `$LogLevelAfter = ($RegSubKey.GetValue('LogLevel')).tostring()`